# *char array to string (two times run code and two different result )

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

Why the same code has two different results, not always is alternate but sometimes string made from *array has length : 4 and different time will be length : 6 . This last 2 characters are random.

```cpp
string linequery;

getline(cin, linequery);

char  * buffer =  new char [4];

size_t lengthh = linequery.copy(buffer, 4, 0);
string stringbuffer(buffer);

cout << " length :" << stringbuffer.length() << endl;
cout << " string buffer : " << stringbuffer << endl;

referencetree.push_back(stringbuffer);

delete []  buffer;
```

OUTPUT with length 6 :

length :6

string buffer : tag1

line query : tag1.tag2~name    :length :14

---

OUTPUT with properly length 4 :

length :4

string buffer : tag1

line query :tag1.tag2~name  : length :14

---

INPUT is the same : tag1.tag2~name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Probably undefined behavior. The code you show is incomplete so we can't reproduce and identify the problem. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Does the indeterminism go away if you use `string stringbuffer(buffer, dotpoint - lastdot)` instead? If so, the string pointed to by `lastdot` may not end in a NUL byte OR `linequery.copy` does not add a NUL byte.

Comment: Without knowing what `linequery` is, it's a bit hard to say for sure. But it appears that `size_t lengthh = linequery.copy(buffer, 4, 0);` copies four characters to `buffer`.  The constructor of `string`, called in the line `string stringbuffer(buffer);` assumes there is a terminating `'\0'` in the passed buffer.    If it is not there (e.g. because four characters have been copied to `buffer` and none of them is `'\0'`_) then the behaviour is undefined. The output of `length :6` suggests that there is no `'\0'` terminator and that your code has copied 6 characters from a four character buffer.

Comment: Thank you ,I Understand  Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the `linequery.copy` does not write a terminating null, so you rely on the next character after `buffer` being a NULL which is not guaranteed. You should build the string with:

```
string stringbuffer(buffer, dotpoint-lastdot);
```

Comment: "which is not guaranteed" it is actually guaranteed to be Undefined Behavior

Comment: Yes it works perfectly . But why sometimes before  despite for  the *char array was define [4]   the string was longer ?

Comment: @Jakinto `std::string` ctor does have no idea what size buffer has. In that form it assumes you pass a null terminated string to it and it leads to UB if there is no termination. If you know the length use another form of `std::string` ctor. And no it does not work in either case, welcome to UB.

Comment: Thank you ,I Understand  Now